# yarn 2 upgrade appears to have broke typescript types, where yarn 1 install of same project succeeds?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

I have been trying to upgrade a typescript monorepo to make use of yarn 2 but am running into an issue where typescript is no longer able to determine certain react props. Since this was working in yarn 1.x, I am thinking there must have been some implicit dependencies being added in yarn 1.x that have to be explicitly defined in yarn 2.x? After hours of looking at project dependencies and node_modules I couldn't determine what needed to change in the production repo and so I created a sample project to reproduce the issue. Hopefully someone is able to point out what I'm missing.

/lib/component/Button.tsx

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button as MuiButton, ButtonProps as MuiButtonProps } from "@material-ui/core";

type ButtonProps = {
  name: "alice" | "bob";
} & MuiButtonProps;

const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>((props: ButtonProps, ref) => {
  const { name, ...other } = props;
  return <MuiButton ref={ref} {...other}>hello {name}, click me</MuiButton>;
});

export default Button;
export type { ButtonProps };
```

/apps/ts-example/App.jsx

```js
import { Button } from "components";

const App = () => {
  return <Button name="bob" variant="outlined" />;
};

export default App;
```

When everything has been installed via yarn 1.x, I can hover over the "name" prop and receive type information as shown below. Additionally, if a prop value is supplied that is not "alice" or "bob" you receive a type error like one would expect.

[image]

After installing via yarn 2.x, when I hover over the "name" prop I just get a "string" type (shown below). Additionally, typescript never gives any error for the prop even if what's supplied is not "alice" or "bob". Which makes sense since typescript appears to no longer understand the type definition.

[image]

I have observed that I can get type information back for the "name" prop if I remove the type intersection with the MuiButtonProps in the `lib/components/Button.jsx` file. However this has the results of the type not knowing about the "base" props from the underlying Material-UI button. Below is the modified type definition.

```js
type ButtonProps = {
  name: "alice" | "bob";
};
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

I'm hoping the problem is obvious based on what I outlined above, but if it's not sufficient, here's the sample repo that reproduces the issue. https://github.com/jereklas/ts-example

- the "main" branch is the yarn 1.x install that is working.
- the "yarn2" branch is the yarn 2.x install that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my yarn.lock file had been deleted and regenerated with a different `@material-ui/types` version which was causing all my problems. It needed to be 5.1.0 and was instead 5.1.8

```
- "@material-ui/types@^5.1.0":
-   version "5.1.0"
-   resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@material-ui/types/-/types-5.1.0.tgz#efa1c7a0b0eaa4c7c87ac0390445f0f88b0d88f2"
-   integrity sha512-7cqRjrY50b8QzRSYyhSpx4WRw2YuO0KKIGQEVk5J8uoz2BanawykgZGoWEqKm7pVIbzFDN0SpPcVV4IhOFkl8A==
+ "@material-ui/types@npm:^5.1.0":
+   version: 5.1.8
+   resolution: "@material-ui/types@npm:5.1.8"
+   peerDependencies:
+     "@types/react": "*"
+   peerDependenciesMeta:
+     "@types/react":
+       optional: true
+   checksum: 543af1b4c0ba8c62f6b4a7f64fd17c8b705c4942c62d4971604e07bb207b834fe7bda97f31d223dc448f66673eb39ceb80b151ddb5ad076506fe515360d572ea
+   languageName: node
+   linkType: hard
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, but it's not material-ui, it's some other dep. I don't understand how updating a dep like this can completely break compilation? And I have even less of an idea how to fix it.

Comment: You might reach out to the maintainer of whatever dependency you're having problems with. They probably will be able to tell you what version of types belong with what version of the dependency. Either that, or go back to a point in your version control where it was all working, and take notes of the versions and then fix your lock file.